# How do I change the color of particles with lamps?

Tags: particles

I want my particles to change colors with lamps, but when I shine a lamp on the particles, they are still white. I made the lamp color purple and increased the energy of the lamp, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try using dupli objects instead of the default halos.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I'm still new to Blender.

Comment: I'll post an answer with pictures in a couple minutes.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long I had to say goodbye to some relatives that were leaving...

Answer (score 2):

[image: Blender Window]

To make your particles "physical objects" make a mesh off scene that you want your particles to duplicate. Then, in the particle menu, scroll down to the "Render" panel and check the "Object" box. In the text entry box select you duplicate object and you're done!

Comment: Can I change the color of the particles with lamps without making them physical objects?

Comment: No. Objects that don't _exist_ can't reflect light. A halo is just a visualization of the xyz coordinates that the particle is keeping track of.

Comment: Any time. . . .